# I cannot remove Sound Booster Driver in Audio MIDI Setup

Tags: audio

[image]I had removed the Sound Booster Driver from my Applications folder on my Mac. For some reason the Sound Booster Driver is still in my Audio Devices and I cannot remove it. I have tried searching all my folders/Applications/Etc. and I cannot find it in any of my folders. Does anyone know how to remove this from my Mac?

Comment: Are there any options when you right-click (Ctrl-click) on the Sound Booster Driver item?

Comment: Fixed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418116/remove-audio-device-which-is-not-kext/418120#418120

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove registered objects from Audio MIDI Setup. You need to get a proper uninstaller for the app.

Direct link: https://soundbooster.froyosoft.com/UninstallSoundBooster.zip

Comment: Thanks! I have removed the Sound Booster driver.