# Remove audio device which is not kext

Tags: audio, kernel-extensions

When I had some problem with the audio (apparently boom crashed in background) I checked the Sound Preferences in System Preferences, and found a extension called `DeviceName`, I don't remember myself installing this, and it doesn't have any kext installed along it, How Do I uninstall it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an audio driver.

Check out the path below to see if you can make progress

```
/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL
```

Restart the audio service

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod" with administrator privileges'
```

Comment: Is there any reason you run `osascript -e` instead of just `sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod`